# Median of the F-distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, special-functions, median

Is the median of the F-distribution with m and n degrees of freedom decreasing in n, for any m?

From experiments it looks like it might be, but I have been unable to prove it.

Comment: Is n the denominator degrees of freedom?

Comment: @Michael yes it is

Comment: Have you looked at tables of the F distribution.  I don't think the tables give percentiles close to 50 but maybe looking at the 25th and the 75th with a gross interpolation would give you an idea whether or not it is true.  I am sure that there are software packages that will give the cumulative F or its inverse and you can see the result from that.

Comment: @Michael yes from software calculation it seems like the result is true. But I am looking for a proof!

Comment: If it is not true the tables could tell you by giving you just one counterexample.  If you need precision you can do numerical integration to a desired level of accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

This officially free to download ["Handbook of Statistical Distributions"](http://www.stat.rice.edu/~dobelman/textfiles/DistributionsHandbook.pdf) shows that (using their notation) the cumulative distribution (cdf) of the F-distribution can be written as the cdf of a transformed Beta variable:
$$\int_{0}^{F_a} f\left(F;m,n\right)dF=1-a=\frac{B_x(\frac m2,\frac n2)}{B(\frac m2,\frac n2)}\equiv G_B(x;\frac m2,\frac n2),\;x=\frac{mF_a}{n+mF_a}$$
Moreover, based on [this source](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.0433.pdf) the median of a $B(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution, for $\alpha>1, \beta>1$ is *approx.* equal to $ \frac {\alpha -\frac 13}{\alpha +\beta -\frac 23}$. In our case this approximate formula holds for $m\gt 2, n \gt2$. For this case then we have (setting $a=\frac 12$)

$$\frac{mF_\frac 12}{n+mF_\frac 12} \approx\frac {\frac m2 -\frac 13}{\frac m2 +\frac n2 -\frac 23}$$
Doing the algebra we arrive at

$$F_\frac 12\approx \frac{n}{3n-2}\frac{3m-2}{m}$$
and so 
$$\text{sign} \left(\frac {\partial}{\partial n} F_\frac 12\right)=\text{sign} \left(\frac {\partial}{\partial n} \frac{n}{3n-2}\right)= \text{sign} \left(3n-2 - 3n\right) \lt 0$$

For the case $\alpha =1 \Rightarrow m=2$ we have (source again)
$$\frac {mF_\frac 12}{n+mF_\frac 12} = 1-\frac {1}{2^{(2/n)}}$$

which leads again to a negative relationship between the median of the F-distribution and the denominator degrees of freedom.

I have no proof for the remaining degrees of freedom. The $F(1,n)$ distribution is the distribution of a squared Student's-t random variable, if that helps.